# UML tool for Qt applications

Tags: qt, uml, class-diagram, tool-uml

Any one knows a reliable UML tool for generating class diagrams from Qt applications?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [BoUML](http://www.bouml.fr/) or [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/). My recommendation is 
Umbrello. It is easy to use and much friendly with Qt.

Comment: Umbrello can import code of C++ (and Qt) project.

Comment: But it can't recognize signals and slots

Answer (score 6):

As of QT-Creator 3.6([released 2015/12](https://wiki.qt.io/ModelEditor)) there will be UML support as well.

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-modeling.html

[image]